# View a log file in Linux dynamically

Tags: linux, logging

I have a log file in .csv format in Linux, that is being updated continuously.
I want to view the log file as it is being updated. Is there any Linux command(s) to do that?

Comment: This is really belonging at serverfault though.

Answer (score 134):

`tail -f yourlog.csv`

Newly appended lines will continuously show.

Answer (score 78):

As others have pointed out, [`tail -f file`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tail) is the most common solution. The problem is that the results just scroll by, and you can't go back and search them unless your terminal supports it and you have enough lines buffered in your terminal.

A less known solution that I like is to use [`less`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/less); if you type <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> while viewing a file with `less`, it will start following the end of the file just like `tail -f`. Alternatively, you can start `less` with `less +F` to enter this mode on startup. At any time, you can type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> to stop following the file, and then page up and down, search using <kbd>/</kbd>, and use `less` just like normal. This can be really helpful if you see something interesting in the log, but it scrolls off screen, or if you want to go back a bit to check on something you might have missed. Once you're done searching around, hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> again to start following the file again.

[`multitail`](http://www.vanheusden.com/multitail/) looks like a nice solution for following multiple files in separate windows; if you view multiple files with `tail -f`, they will each be interleaved with each other (with headers to distinguish them), which may not be the way you want to watch them.

`tail -F` (that is capital `-F`, as opposed to lowercase `-f`) is a non-standard flag (available on Linux, Cygwin, MacOS X, FreeBSD and NetBSD), that works better for watching log files, which may be rotated occasionally; it's common for a process to rename a log file, and then create a new log file in its place, in order to avoid any one log file getting too big. `tail -f` will keep following the old file, which is no longer the active log file, while `tail -F` will watch for a new file being created, and start following that instead. If you're using `less` to follow the file, you can use the `--follow-name` flag to make `less` act this way as well.

(thanks to ephemient for the tips on `less +F` and `less --follow-name`)

Comment: `less +F` will automatically enter follow-tail mode, and `less --follow-name` will act more like `tail -F`.  I find these quite useful :-)

Comment: Ah, thanks. I wasn't aware of the command line switches.

Comment: Bonus: if you search (`/`) something in less, and then enter tail mode (`F`), it'll highlight matches on incoming lines.

Answer (score 11):

tail -f foo.csv

Answer (score 11):

Just in case you want to monitor multiple files, there is a nice tool called [multitail](http://www.vanheusden.com/multitail/examples.html) that lets you merge the output from two or more files and track them in real time.  multitail also lets you navigate back and forth in the monitored file(s).

Comment: +1 for something other than `tail -f`

Answer (score 9):

`tail -f` and all its friends are old school. `multitail` looks better but the *real* way to burn CPU watching your log files is to use [glTail](http://www.rubyinside.com/gltail-sexy-log-file-visualization-using-ruby-627.html).

Answer (score 5):

```
less -S '-#' 4 /var/log/logfile
```

`-S` will stop the annoying line-wrapping.

`-#` `4` will set the horizontal scrolling step to four columns, instead of the default of half the screen.

Press the End key to refresh.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to check if the question was still active.

Comment: Don't be sorry, this is super helpful. I added `+F` to this and got everything I wanted in a log file monitor

Answer (score 0):

tail -lf logfile.csv.

If you logged on to GUI, you can use mousepad to view the log dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

vsConsole FileView may help if you prefer to monitor your logs via a web application.
See the demo at http://demo.vamonossoftware.com/

Requires you run a java app server, deploy vsConsole to it, and run agents on the server containing the logs - so I'm guessing its a more heavy weight solution than what you need here. (Its good for dev/testing teams who just want to click on a log file to see it rather than ssh, cd, tail etc)